# GORM Criteria Sort by Absolute Value

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have being working with GORM criterias since a while and I really love them (helps a lot to keep the complexity down and to make the code understandable).

I am having at the moment some issues while trying to get the result sorted by the absolute value of a property:

```
Person.createCriteria(){
    order("abs(rating)", "desc")
}
```

Which is of course like this not working.

Does anyone have any idea what would be the proper way of doing it? (Sort by absolute values in GORM)

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out anything to sort by abs directly in the criteria, but sorting after the criteria would work:

```
    def personInstanceList = Person.withCriteria {
      //whatever is necessary for your query
    }
    personInstanceList.sort {a, b-> java.lang.Math.abs(b.rating) <=> java.lang.Math.abs(a.rating)}  //b.rating <=> a.rating sorts desc
```

Comment: Hi Kelly, Thanks for your answer, but this solution does not work in my case. Sorting the list after querying it, means that you have to query the whole data set from the db, which is extrem unefficient for big sets (> 10'000). Thas why I have to do this at a SQL level!

Comment: That is not what i was looking for, but after lot of hours trying to find how to solve my problem, i decide to use your solution. Thanks :)!!